# Is it a way using in Symfony php-amqplib rabbitmq-bundle to turn of the exeptions when rabbitmq is down?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I want to catch in a Symfony PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException but is always the vendor taking care of the error.
Is it a way to configure php-amqplib rabbitmq-bundle to pass the exception to the app ?

Comment: What version of the package ?